# Org mode: Insert the result of a table formula between two existing columns

Tags: org-mode, org-table, spreadsheet, formula

I have a very simple table like this:

```
| A | B |  C |
|---+---+----|
| 1 | 2 | 15 |
| 1 | 2 | 32 |
| 1 | 2 | 81 |
```

I want to apply a formula that calculate the sum between A and B and insert the result just after the B column but before the C one. The formula is easy but…

```
#+TBLFM: $? = $1+$2
```

…I don't know what to put in place of `$?`.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Adding a column is a one-time operation that is best done through external means, not through a formula. While in column `C`, say `M-x org-table-insert-column` which inserts an empty third column, leaving the formula then as `$3 = $1 + $2`.

Comment: I agree with @NickD. It would be helpful to know why you are trying to add one more column to the table. Thus, we would know whether this is a [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Answer (score -1):

An elisp formula can do the trick :

```
  | A | B |   |  C |
  |---+---+---+----|
  | 1 | 2 | 3 | 15 |
  | 1 | 2 | 3 | 32 |
  | 1 | 2 | 3 | 81 |
  #+TBLFM: $4='(progn(org-table-analyze)(when (eq 3 org-table-current-ncol) (org-table-insert-column)) (+ $1 $2));N
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me, it produces a weird result. Care to elaborate on what does this elisp formula do?

Comment: The trouble with using a formula to do this, is that the next time you refresh the table, the formula is applied again (and again and again...) For non-idempotent operations, this is obviously going to cause problems. That's why I recommended that for such one-time operations, you do *NOT* use a formula (or if you do, you then delete the part of the formula that does that particular operation.

Comment: It works the first time, but try doing `C-c C-c` on your formula a second time: what do you see?

Comment: @Nicryc. Your question is certainly part of a much larger question, the context of which I do not know and which should be treated as such. My solution is kind of a joke of taking your question at face value. At home it works, but I will not use such a solution under any circumstances.

Comment: It's hard to show it here so I'm just gonna describe it. It creates two new columns (`$4` and `$5`) and put the result of the first row in the `$5` column and the result of the following rows in the `$4` column. Besides it automatically change the beginning of my formula to `$5=`.

I know this is some weird question but in fact my tables are completely re-generated each time I change some values in a bigger root table using the [org-aggregate](https://github.com/tbanel/orgaggregate) module.

Comment: Use source code blocks, not formulas.